# Test if a single sample is likely to have come from the same distribution as a dataset

Tags: t-test, small-sample

A certain experimental design foresees collecting 100 datapoints under condition A and exactly 1 datapoint under condition B. It may be assumed that in both cases the data is normally distributed. Is it possible to test the null hypothesis that both datasets have originated from the same distribution?

- I have considered the independent t-test, but it requires more than 1 datapoint in each dataset to estimate variances
- I have considered the one-sample t-test, but it tests for a different null hypothesis, and thus it seems that it is not what I want.

I'm tempted to estimate mean and variance under condition A, assume that it is the true mean and variance, calculate the CDF and CCDF of the datapoint under condition B using that distribution, and test if either of those is below pvalue/2. Problem is that his approach does not account for uncertainty in estimating distribution under condition A. Surely, there must be a more robust way to do this

Comment: the t-test does not need more than one point in each group, so long as you are willing to assume that variances are equal between the groups.  Since your null hypothesis is that "both datasets originated from the same distribution" this seems reasonable.  Without this assumption there isn't anything you can do since you don't have any other info on the variation in group B.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva, are you certain of this? When I look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test) of the test statistic for the independent two-sample t-test with equal variances, it clearly requires estimates of sample variances of both samples, which is impossible for the group that has only 1 point. Further, I have tried this in python, and the routine ttest_ind returns NAN if either of the groups has only one point.

Comment: Yes, I am certain of this.  All you need for a t-test is an estimate of the pooled standard deviation.  If only one sample can contribute to this then ignore the other one.   The definition you linked to only requires $s_{X_2}$ if $n_2$ is greater than 1.  When $n_2=1$ it becomes $s_p=s_{X_1}$.  R will run the test, eg: `t.test(rnorm(100),1,var.equal = TRUE)` works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I guess python is using a different definition than R. I'll see if I can find another library or just write the test by hand

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I have made a request to the scipy community to improve this feature in a future release. Do you by any chance know where I could find a mathematical proof for this case?

Comment: Any textbook should do it.  The usual definition for pooled standard deviation (eg the Wiki link you sent) works fine.  Just note that when $n_2=1$ the coefficient for $s_{X_2}$ is zero, so $s_{X_2}$ is not needed for the calculation.  Intuitively, if you can assume that the variation in condition A is the same as in condition B then it doesn't matter which condition the information on variation comes from.